# How to debug stand-alone javascript in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Visual Studio is a wonderful IDE for debugging. Currently, Javascript is usually debugged using Firebug or Chrome developer tools. For websites containing javascript, I understand it is not possible to use Visual Studio. What about stand-alone javascript? I would like to debug stand-alone javascript functions in Visual Studio. If this is possible, may I know how can it be done?

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: What do you mean stand-alone javascript and why can't you debug that javascript with Firebug or Chrome dev-tools?

Comment: I can but Visual Studio is a friendlier IDE. Stand-alone javascript means javascript that does not involve any web-related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done. The code would have to be in some kind of web project, and then you would have to use IE as your main development browser. Personally I started out years ago using the Visual Studio/IE debugging but find it prohibitively slow now.

Anyway this point is moot anyway because you don't want to debug a web app :)

As far as an alternative solution I can thoroughly recommend [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) by JetBrains, they really do a bang up job with the IDEs... and this is coming from a die hard Visual Studio guy! While I can't profess to being an expert with it the times I have used it I found the configuration reasonably easy, and it fully supports nodejs and all that stuff.

Hope this helps even though it's not the answer you were hoping for